# Active button does not work in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a navbar and if I click one of menu buttons it does not change the current button's color.
In Laravel it works perfect and I do not know why it does not work if I do this in without any framework. Can anyone help me, please?
navbar:

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse activebtn" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                <li><a href="index.php" >Comments<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="profilepage.php">Profile</a></li> 
                <li><a href="allusers.php">Users</a></li> 
            </ul>
 </div>
```

javascript:

```
 var loc = window.location.pathname;

$('.activebtn').find('a').each(function() {
$(this).toggleClass('active', $(this).attr('href') == loc);
});
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-default .activebtn a.active {
 padding: 0 21px;
 line-height: 33px;
 color: #56c93d;
 background: #323637;
 border-left: 0;
 border-right: 0;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #56c93d;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #484e4f, #323637);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #484e4f, #323637);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #484e4f, #323637);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #484e4f, #323637);
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #151717, inset 0 -1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #151717, inset 0 -1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
 border-bottom-color: #56c93d;
}
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery library in your project ?

Comment: Do you have any error in chrome console ?

Comment: Yes, I included jQuery in library because other javascript code works on the site. And there is no error in chrome console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code *almost* works as written -- assuming that the DOM is ready by the time this script runs -- but `window.location.pathname` comes with a leading "/" which isn't included in your anchor hrefs, so the strings never match.  To correct this all you need to do is include that leading "/" in the anchors, or else clean up the pathname variable to match what's inside the href attributes:

```js
// var loc = window.location.pathname;
// Setting a fake location for demo:
var loc = "/profilepage.php";

$('.exampleone').find('a').each(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active', $(this).attr('href') === loc);
});
```

```css
a {color: #000}
.active {color: #F00}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="exampleone">
  <!-- changed the hrefs here -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/index.php">Comments<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/profilepage.php">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="/allusers.php">Users</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing in the javascript you posted that refers to the `click()` function.  You're just going through all `a` elements and binding the toggle function to them, which doesn't do anything.  Try replacing `each` with `click` like this:

```
var loc = window.location.pathname;

$('.activebtn').find('a').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).attr('href', loc);
});
```

If that doesn't help please create a fiddle or code pen so we can look at your code.

My fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bratjy5n/3/)

Comment: I replaced, but it still does not work. I do not see any error in chrome console neither.

Comment: Lol, my bad, I didn't finish reading the code.  I updated the answer.  Additionally, you were incorrectly trying to chain the href attribute change inside the toggleClass method.

Comment: This seems to misunderstand the purpose of the code in the question --- he's not trying to add click handlers as far as I can tell;  looks like it's intended to run once on page load: check each anchor, compare its href to the pathname, and add the 'active' class if they match.

Comment: The first sentence of the question says he wants to click the button and have it change color.  OP if my edited code does not help you, please clarify your question and provide a working code sample for us to see exactly whats going on.

Comment: Note that the 'buttons' lead to different pages, so changing a color on the page the user just left doesn't have much effect....